# How to remove redundant rows in a data.frame (by columns [1, 2] and vice versa)?

Tags: r, dataframe, phyloseq

I obtained a distance.class table where samples where compared against each other to calculate an index. As a result, each value is duplicated as well as self comparisons occur. See example table below:

|  | Sample1 | Sample2 | Sample3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample1 | 0 | 0.5 | 1 |
| Sample2 | 0.5 | 0 | 0.8 |
| Sample3 | 1 | 0.8 | 0 |

I already removed the self comparisons (sample1 vs sample1 etc.)
But I do not know how to remove the redundant values (i. e. the upper half of the table). Desired output is a table like below, which I can then melt into a data.frame to build plots with. The samples are also of a specific type which I want to use to build the plots.

|  | Sample1 | Sample2 | Sample3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample1 |  |  |  |
| Sample2 | 0.5 |  |  |
| Sample3 | 1 | 0.8 |  |

| Var1 | Var2 | Type1 | Type2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample1 | Sample2 | a | b | 0.5 |
| Sample1 | Sample3 | a | a | 1 |
| Sample2 | Sample3 | b | a | 0.8 |

Comment: Can you share the step before your first result? You can probably modify your code to go directly to your desired output.

Comment: Hi @ktiu
       This is the code I used:
`library(phyloseq)`            
`library(rehsape2)`                 

`library(dplyr)`            

`# calculate distances and coerce into matrix`  
`# this generates the first table in my starting post`  
`wu = phyloseq::distance(physeqObject, DistanceMeasure)`  
`wu.m = melt(as.matrix(wu))  %>%`  
        `mutate_if(is.factor,as.character)`  

`# remove self-comparison`  
`wu.m = wu.m %>%`  
    `filter(as.character(Var1) != as.character(Var2)) %>%`  
    `mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)`

Comment: # get sample data from phyloseq object and combine with with distance matrix 
# this generates the last table from my starting post

`sd = as.matrix(physeqObject@sam_data) %>%
        as.data.frame(sd) %>%
        select(sample, sampleType) %>%
        mutate_if(is.factor,as.character)`


  `colnames(sd) = c("Var1", "Type1")`
  `wu.sd = left_join(wu.m, sd, by = "Var1")`

  `colnames(sd) = c("Var2", "Type2")`
  `wu.sd = left_join(wu.sd, sd, by = "Var2")`

Comment: This is all very hard to reproduce. My tip is to look into `usedist::dist_make()`, but in order to tailor it to your code, it would be necessary that you provide us with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610) that we can copy and paste to better understand the issue and test possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, with `usedist::dist_make()` I was able to produce the intended solution.

After generating the class "dist" matrix calling `phyloseq::distance()`, I extracted the grouping variables from the phyloseq object with:

```
group2samp <- list() 
    group_list <- get_variable(sample_data(physeq), group) 
    for (groups in levels(group_list)) { # loop over the no. of group levels
        target_group <- which(group_list == groups) 
        group2samp[[ groups ]] <- sample_names(physeq)[target_group] 
    }
```

Then I melted the resulting "group2samp" list and rearranged the order of the first column to match with my distance matrix:

```
library(reshape2)    
item_groups = melt(group2samp)

library(dplyr)
item_groups = arrange(item_groups, value)
# needed to reverse the column to match with my distance matrix
item_groups = item_groups[order(nrow(item_groups):1),]
item_groups = item_groups$L1 #extract only grouping variable

library(usedist)
distances = dist_groups(distance_matrix, item_groups)

distances
     Item1    Item2      Group1      Group2                          Label   Distance
1    sample9  sample8       Patch      Plaque       Between Patch and Plaque 0.94344640
2    sample9 sample70       Patch nonlesional  Between nonlesional and Patch 0.60253312
3    sample9 sample69       Patch       Patch                   Within Patch 0.62086228
```